# Docker automatically changes port in URL

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I built two WordPress websites, one bound to port `9000` and one to `8000`. They are both connected to the same MySQL database.

When I access the port `8000` it works perfectly and connects to both the website and the database.

On the other side, when I access the port `9000` it just automatically redirects me to the port `8000` and to its website. Any reason why this may happen?

This is the `docker-compose` file:

Tried to clear the cache and tried it on Firefox (default browser is Chrome) but it still happens.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress

   second_wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "9000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress

volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

Comment: Do you have a Http Client like Postman or Http Client Extension for VS Code? If yes, what response do you get when you do a simple `GET <URL>`?

Comment: It gives a 301 with the port 8000 URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that both sites used the same DATABASE inside mySQL, the solution was to create different databases in mySQL and assign each website to it.

Then the wordpress sites will take the info from different databases and not route.

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://localhost:9000/wp-admin/install.php to install your second instance.

Be aware that the configuration is stored in files (in /var/www/html/) inside the container and will be lost when you stop the container. So you'll have to install it again when you restart.

If you want to save the configuration, you can create a volume and map it to /var/www/html using something like this

```
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
     volumes:
       - wordpress:/var/www/html
```

and

```
volumes:
  wordpress:
```

Comment: When i go to the URL like u mentioned it tells me this:

`Already Installed
You appear to have already installed WordPress. To reinstall please clear your old database tables first.`

Then when i log in it logs me into the machine with port 9000

Comment: So does that fix your redirection problem?

Comment: No, when i log in it stills redirects me to the 8000 port/website and i cannot configure the website connected to port 9000 because it says the above.

Comment: If you do `docker-compose down` and delete the database volume (so you've cleaned up everything) and then start it up again, does it still say that the second site is already installed? That seems very strange if it does.

Comment: Yep, did `docker-compose down` then deleted all the volumes and made sure all the containers are also deleted.

After i do `docker-compose up -d` again the sites go up, i can install the .php on either, in the second i install it on one of them (either 8000 or 9000) then the other one will say it's already installed and allow me a log in to the other one.

Comment: I'm getting the same result. Very strange.

Comment: Is it intentionally that you share the database between the two instances? I'm thinking that maybe the installation of the first site is stored in the database. Then the second site sees it and pulls it from there.

Comment: Yes, i want the two sites to be on the same DB.
Atleast on the same DB container

Comment: Like u said they are running on the same database in the same mySQL container, when i created a second DB for them it worked.